# Filter for second to last available day of month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` with where `df.index` is `DatetimeIndex`. I am trying to filter for the second to last **available** days.

`tseries.offsets.DateOffset` may return dates that are not contained in my list if I am not mistaken which is not what I'm looking for.

I have tried:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).tail(2)
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).loc(-2)
```

`df`:

```
             value
2020-08-29     0
2020-08-31     0
2020-09-01     0
2020-09-25     0
2020-09-26     0
2020-09-30     0
```

to get:

```
            value
2020-08-29     0
2020-09-26     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to get the second to last day of the month for the days listed. To get that, you can use the following code if you have unique dates in the date column. If you have some duplicated dates, then you may have to try another approach.

With this approach, you are finding the `max` date per month (`dt.month`) and comparing to one row before to filter for the rows that are the second to last of the month for the listed dates:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2020-08-29',
  1: '2020-08-31',
  2: '2020-09-01',
  3: '2020-09-25',
  4: '2020-09-26',
  5: '2020-09-30'},
 'value': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).sort_values()
m = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Date'].transform('max') == df['Date'].shift(-1))
df = df[m]
df

Out[27]: 
        Date  value
0 2020-08-29      0
4 2020-09-26      0
```

If it is helpful, I break down each side of the equation for `m` (`m` stands for "mask" since we are doing boolean masking/indexing) into `m1` and `m2` to show you how it works. Then, I create columns for m1, m2 and m, so you can see how all of the logic works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2020-08-29',
  1: '2020-08-31',
  2: '2020-09-01',
  3: '2020-09-25',
  4: '2020-09-26',
  5: '2020-09-30'},
 'value': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).sort_values()
m1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Date'].transform('max')
m2 = df['Date'].shift(-1)
m = (m1 == m2)
df['Max Date Per Month'] = m1
df['Shifted Date'] = m2
df['Keep/Drop'] = m
df
Out[33]: 
        Date  value Max Date Per Month Shifted Date  Keep/Drop
0 2020-08-29      0         2020-08-31   2020-08-31       True
1 2020-08-31      0         2020-08-31   2020-09-01      False
2 2020-09-01      0         2020-09-30   2020-09-25      False
3 2020-09-25      0         2020-09-30   2020-09-26      False
4 2020-09-26      0         2020-09-30   2020-09-30       True
5 2020-09-30      0         2020-09-30          NaT      False
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `duplicated`

```
df = df[df.index.strftime('%Y-%m').duplicated()]
Out[22]: 
            value
2020-08-31      0
2020-09-25      0
2020-09-26      0
2020-09-30      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Take last two days of month then take first one of the two for each month

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).tail(2)
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).head(1)
```